# Determining the order of the pole for the given function.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to understand zeros and poles in complex analysis. Could you explain in detail how can I determine the order of the pole for the given function.

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1+e^z}$$

Comment: First identify where $1+e^z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $1+e^{z}=0$ at some $z_0$. The order of the zero is the order of the pole of $1/(1+e^{z})$ which is determined by how many of the first terms in the following series expansions vanish:
$$
         1+e^{z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left.\left[\frac{d^n}{dz^n}(1+e^z)\right]\right|_{z=z_0}(z-z_0)^n
$$
In this case, it is easy to see that only the first term vanishes because, if $e^{z_0}+1=0$, then $\frac{d}{dz}(e^{z}+1)=e^{z}$ is $-1$ at $z_0$. So all of the zeros of $1+e^z$ are simple, which means all of the poles of $1/(1+e^z)$ are simple.